# bicubic sampling example using pixel bender?

Tags: flash, pixel-bender

I am new to pixel bender and wondering if anyone knows how bicubic [down]-sampling would be implemented using adobe's pixel bender?

Here is an example of how Bilinear [down]-sampling [can be implemented](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2009/03/11/bilinear-resampling-with-flash-player-and-pixel-bender/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried. See if it is what you want http://blog.onthewings.net/2009/08/25/bicubic-resampling-by-pixel-bender/